# SQL query - limit resulting query rows based on non sorted value

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables

table 1

```
per_id | per_name
-------+-----------   
1      | joe
2      | mike
x      | xxxx
```

and a second table

```
per_id | job_q
-------+-------    
1      | 500
1      | 250
2      | 125
2      |  10
3      |  54
...
```

I need a third table where I sum all the job_q and group by per_name and order by job_q asc

table 3

```
per_name | job_q
---------+---------    
joe      | 750
mike     | 135
...
```

How can I limit my results up to a specific per_name while keeping my job_q ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select t1.per_name, sum(t2.job_q) job_q
  from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
  on t2.per_id = t1.per_id
  group by t1.per_name
)
select * from cte
order by job_q desc
limit (
  select count(*) from cte where job_q >= (
    select job_q from cte where per_name = 'mike'
  )
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hSWW2i7GrJ9bQDt1SJUDC5/0)

Comment: i get Query executed successfully but no results...maybe because table1 and 2 don't share the same name?(per_id on table one is pr_id) coding on db browser

Comment: I don't know your actual data. Of course you change 'mike' to a valid name from your data.

Comment: You must make changes to the names of the columns and/or tables

Comment: Execute just `select * from cte`. Do you get any data?

Comment: but i still get Query executed successfully

Comment: If you don't get results then by the cte then either you did not make all the changes or your data cannot be joined like you posted in the question. Post the code as you changed it.

Comment: with cte as (
  select t1.Surname, sum(t2.job_quality) job_quality
  from LOAD_W t1 inner join TcS_T t2
  on t2.per_id = t1.pr_id
  group by t1.Surname
)
select * from cte
order by job_quality desc
limit (
  select count(*) from cte where job_quality >= (
    select job_quality from cte where Surname = 'xxxxxx'
  )
);

Comment: Execute this: `select t1.Surname, sum(t2.job_quality) job_quality 
  from LOAD_W t1 inner join TcS_T t2 on t2.per_id = t1.pr_id 
  group by t1.Surname`. Do you get any results?

Comment: the tables include more unrelated to this query columns, is that a problem?

Comment: No it is not. If the tables can be joined by per_id and pr_id, meaning there are matching values then you would see results. Did you execute the above code?

Comment: i did a mistake with the correct table,i should be looking at LOAD_W1 the primary code works fine...Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - I'm assuming that the OP is talking about qsql which is part of the KDB database (since the `q` label/tag was used)

Something like this?

```
q)`job_q xdesc select sum job_q by per_name from (t2 lj 1!t1) where per_name in `joe`mike
per_name| job_q
--------| -----
joe     | 750
mike    | 135
```

Assumes your tables are in-memory.

Or if you want to filter by ID:

```
q)`job_q xdesc select sum job_q by per_name from (t2 lj 1!t1) where per_id=2
per_name| job_q
--------| -----
mike    | 135
```